# How do I filter location array by city (location) Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I can't find any articles in Google Maps documentation hope somebody here did or know how to achieve that what I need.

So basically I have `array of locations`

***example of array***

```
const array = [
  {
    latitude: 37.783476,
    longitude: -122.425412,
  }
]
```

Now I need to filter this array based on city (e.g San Francisco).

How can I achieve this?
Any links to documentation or any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Try getting latitude/longitude of the cities you want to filter by first.

Comment: [Reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse) allows you to find the city associated to the given latitude/longitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using reverse geocoding.

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fatty/bdartuph/12/

Here i have taken two coordinates in array - san francisco and new york. So the array will get filtered by the city you write in input box and will get store in filteredArray.

```js
var coordArray = [{
    latitude: 37.783476,
    longitude: -122.425412,
  },
  {
    latitude: 40.730885,
    longitude: -73.997383,
  }
];

$("#btn").click(function() {
  var filteredArray = [];
  var cityName = $("#cityName").val();
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  for (var i = 0; i < coordArray.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordArray[i].latitude, coordArray[i].longitude);
    geocoder.geocode({
      'latLng': latlng
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var address = results[0].formatted_address.split(',');
        alert("" + address[1]);
        if (address[1].toLocaleLowerCase().trim() == cityName.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
          filteredArray.push(coordArray[i]);
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<input id="cityName" type="text" placeholder="write city name">
<input id="btn" type="button" value="filter coordinates" />
```